# How to split an array based on a certain value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I currently have an array of location based information similar to below (which is already sorted by time). The first key/value is event which represents the start of a journey (00), a running journey (01) and an end of a journey (10).

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[1] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[2] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[3] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[4] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[5] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[6] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[7] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[8] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[9] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[10] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[11] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[12] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[13] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[14] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[15] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[16] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[17] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[18] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
)
```

How can I split the array even further so it creates a new array for every journey so I would end up with this:

```
Array (
[0] => Array (
[0] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[1] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[2] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[3] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[4] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[5] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
)
[1] => Array (
[0] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[1] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[2] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[3] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[4] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[5] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[6] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[7] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
)
...
)
```

I haven't tried anything yet (except for googling) as I don't really know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a custom solution like so:

```
 $outputArray = array(); $currentArray = array();
 foreach($inputArray as $key=>$subArray) {
   if($subArray['event']==00) {
      $outputArray[] = $currentArray;
      $currentArray = array($subArray);
   } else {
      $currentArray[] = $subArray;
   }
 }
 $outputArray[] = $currentArray;
 array_shift($outputArray);
```

put in $inputArray and then get out $outputArray.  Enjoy!

Comment: It almost works. Seems to miss the last one off though. - $outputArray array (3)
    array(0)
    array (6)
    array (8)

Comment: you are correct... try the new edit and it should work. Srry about that.

Comment: Genius ;) Now I will go through it and hope to learn from you!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$journey = array ( 
[0] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[1] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[2] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[3] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[4] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[5] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[6] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[7] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[8] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[9] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[10] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[11] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[12] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[13] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[14] => Array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[15] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[16] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[17] => Array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
[18] => Array ( [event] => 10 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 )
)

$journeygrouping = array();

while(!empty($journey)){
$temp = array_pop($journey);

if(isset($journeygrouping[$temp['event']])){
  array_push($journeygrouping[$temp['event']], $temp);
} else {
  $journeygrouping[$temp['event']] = array();
  array_push($journeygrouping[$temp['event']], $temp);
}
}
```

this code should create an array structure like:

```
array(
[00] => array([0] => array([event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111) [1]=>array ( [event] => 00 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111 ))
[01] => array([0]=>array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111) [1]=>array ( [event] => 01 [time] => 1329293878 [lat] => 66.66666 [lon] => 11.11111)  )
);
```

and so on...

Comment: But this creates a grouped array based on the event and not each journey? Or am I missing something? $journeygrouping array (3)
    '10' => array (3)
    '1' => array (13)
    '0' => array (3)