# PHP split array based on value

Tags: php, array-splice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to split an array based on a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354684/how-to-split-an-array-based-on-a-certain-value)

Here is an example array I want to split:

(0, 1 ,2 ,3, 0, 4, 5)

How do I split it in 2 array like this?

(0, 1 ,2 ,3)
(0, 4, 5)

Basically I want to check if the value of an element is zero and then create an array of all the elements until I find another zero. I can't seem to come up with a solution to this.

Comment: array_keys() [with search value] then array_slice(), but i'm sure one one as a niftier idea

Answer (score 5):

```
$array = array(0, 1 ,2 ,3, 0, 4, 5);
$result = array();
$index = -1;
foreach ($array as $number) {
    if ($number == 0) {
        $index++;
    }
    $result[$index][] = $number;
}
echo print_r($result, true);
```

You'll end with the following.

```
array(
    0 => array(0, 1, 2, 3),
    1 => array(0, 4, 5)
)
```

Comment: If the array does not start with the search value, the first key in the result array would be -1 and not 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = -1;
$newArr = array();
$array = array(0,1,2,3,0,4,5,6);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if($value == 0) 
    $x++;

  $newArr[$x][] = $value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to break up into String arrays for each appearance of 0, but I see now that you have an array, not a string. As suggested above now, you can use the inverse, [PHP implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Answer (score 0):

First concatenate the elements, then split using `0` and then separate them again by prefixing `0` e.g. below

```
$concatenatedStr = implode(',', $array);
$indx = 0;
$fragments = array();
$fragementStrings= explode("0,", $concatenatedStr);
foreach($fragementStrings as $fragementString) {
  //you get your fragements here 
  $fragments[$indx++][] = explode(",", "0,".$fragementString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$a=array(0, 1 ,2 ,3, 0, 4, 5);
$b =array();
$k=-1;
foreach($a as $key=>$val)
{
    if($val==0)
    {
      $k++;  
    }

    $b[$k][]=$val;
}


echo"<pre>";



print_r($b[0]);

print_r($b[1]);


foreach($b as $key=>$val)
{
    echo"<pre>";
    echo $val;
    echo"</pre>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to a comment, [`array_keys`](http://php.net/array_keys) can be used to search for all keys containing the value you search for (zero in your case).

You then can loop over these positions and *slice the array* (see [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice)) into the parts.

Example ([Demo](http://eval.in/4496)):

```
$keys  = array_keys($array, 0);
$parts = [];
$last  = 0;

foreach ($keys as $key)
{
    $last !== $key 
        && $parts[] = array_slice($array, $last, $key - $last, true);    
    $last = $key;
}

$parts[] = isset($key) ? array_slice($array, $key, null, true) : $array;
```

This variant even preserves original keys, exemplary `$parts` output:

```
array(2) {
  [0] => array(4) {
    [0] => int(0)
    [1] => int(1)
    [2] => int(2)
    [3] => int(3)
  }
  [1] => array(3) {
    [4] => int(0)
    [5] => int(4)
    [6] => int(5)
  }
}
```

---

Another alternative could be similar to some other answers outlined. The following variant does preserve keys, too:

```
$array = [0, 1 ,2 ,3, 0, 4, 5];
$parts = [];
$index = 0;

foreach ($array as $key => $number)
{
    $number == 0 and $key and $index++;
    $parts[$index][$key] = $number;
}
```

Output ([Demo](http://eval.in/4511)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 4
            [6] => 5
        )

)
```