# PHP how to populate array from array by value

Tags: php, arrays

Thanks lets say i have array like this

```
$array = array('1','1','3','1','2','3','2','2','2','3');
```

i want to create arrays from the above array but of common elements like

```
    $arr1 = ('1','1','3');
    $arr2 = ('1','2','3');
    $arr3 = ('2','2','2','3');
```

where conditions finding value 3 from array.
Is there such a PHP function, I had a browse of the manual but could not see what I was looking for.

Comment: `but of common elements`, what's that mean?

Comment: array_chunk() perhaps, but why do the first two arrays have three elements each and the last have 4 entries?

Comment: Are you wanting to split an array where a value is less than the previous value?

Comment: Just loop and add to an array until you hit 3, then create a new array and repeat

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP split array based on value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852737/php-split-array-based-on-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what did you mean, but I guess this code will meet your needs

```
$result = array();
$needle = '3';
$haystack = array('1','1','3','1','2','3','2','2','2','3');
$tmp = array();
foreach ($haystack as $var){
    $tmp[] = $var;
    if ($var == $needle){
        $result[] = $tmp;
        $tmp = array();
    }
}
if (!empty($tmp)){
    $result[] = $tmp;
}
```

And the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
            [3] => 3
        )

)
```